# Howto debug BSOD when connecting, disconnecting USB

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I am running Windows XP, SP3, all updates installed.

When I plug in or disconnect a USB device, I get a BSOD:

0000007E or 000000BE

and the two drivers that are listed are either fastfat.sys and kmixer.sys.

I've uninstalled all USB devices in the Device Manager, I'd re-installed my WACOM drivers, all to no avail.

I am not sure how to proceed in debugging this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Might be useful if you could elaborate on what *types* of USB devices trigger the error - peripherals, flash drives, external HD, everything, etc?

Comment: Sure... USB jump drives, MicroSD cards plugged into USB adapters, SD card plugged into the front media slot, Western Digital 2.5" passport drives, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the [system file checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310747) to verify that all the system drivers are undamaged/unmodified?

The [MS Knowledge Base Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330182) on the `STOP 0x0000007E` error (aka `SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`) provides some general advice on things to try.
It looks like you've tried a few already, but it's probably worth a look.

I can't find a dedicated article for `Stop 0xBE`, but the friendly version of the error is `ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY`, and from what I find its causes can be much wider (bad drivers, bad software, bad hardware, bad BIOS, and so on). So that doesn't helps much.

Answer (score 1):

Along with DMA57361's suggestion of checking for corrupted system files, the kmixer.sys is a sound driver, you might see if there is an update for your sound driver, also scan your system for malware or a rootkit.

GMER rootkit remover http://www.majorgeeks.com/GMER_d5198.html

Sophos rootkit remover http://www.majorgeeks.com/Sophos_Ant...kit_d5238.html

Sysprot rootkit remover http://www.majorgeeks.com/SysProt_An...kit_d5708.html

TrendMicro Rootkit Buster http://www.majorgeeks.com/Trend_Micr...ter_d5427.html

F-Secure rootkit remover  http://www.f-secure.com/en_EMEA/security/tools/blacklight/